# Can't refactor code: one or more predefined type(s) missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a medium sized solution (~15 project) where I recently added some extra projects. And after that I need to rename the namespace for those added projects. And in past times it was just to change the namespace and I got the suggestion to refactor with preview. Now all I get is a message box saying:

*"The refactoring operation cannot be performed because one or more predefined type(s) that are required for refactoring could not be found in your solution."*

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score -2):

The problem was that I had manually done changes in my csproj file. And some of those changes was bad. Unfortunately I just made a revert from my SVN repository, so I don't know exactly what the problem was...  Sorry for that.